# how to make unix command use multiple CPUs

Tags: unix, command, cpu, processor

How can I make a unix command (say a one-liner using cut and awk on a HUGE file) use all 16 cores instead of just 1? This isn't a program where I can use -j and specify the number of CPUs to use...

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried GNU parallel to parallelize jobs? See http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: For your task you should look into the --pipe option demonstrated here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ntxT-47VPA

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to split your input file into a number of pieces and then launch separate shell pipelines for each piece. Multiple processes will take multiple cores.

Comment: but all of the CPUs won't be utilized at the same time right? Will there be moments where any certain CPU is not used?

Comment: Multiple processes should use separate CPUs but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you use *both* `cut` and `awk` in the same pipeline, they'll probably run on different CPUs, so you will use two of them. There isn't a simple way to set up a short pipeline like that to use more CPUs than the number of steps in the pipeline.

Comment: I have a long command, say something like (cut -f 5 HUGEFILE.txt | awk '{print $1+$2}'). The computer I'm working on says its using 100% of 1 cpu, and that the rest are inactive.